# How to get values of non-asp controls in an asp.net project?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to know how to get the values from non-asp controls in my C# code? Can someone help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply the `runat="server"` tag to standard HTML controls, as well. Absent doing that, you can also check the `Request` object in your code.

```
string foo = Request.Form["controlName"];
```

Comment: I can't use runat="server" because it is for jquery datepicker, and if I add runat="server" it breaks... Can't seem to get Request.Form working either. For controlName, would that be the id of my text box?

Comment: That would be the actual name. `<input name="controlName" type="text" id="whatever" />`.

Answer (score 0):

If the control is embedded inside a `<form>` tag you can use the `Request["<control name>"]`